# Background image on every page with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to get a background image on every page of a document, but I just get it on the first page with the following code!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage, lipsum, tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node[opacity=.1, inner sep=0pt] at(current page.center){\includegraphics[width=14cm, angle=45]{pic.png}};
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `eso-pic` for that. (There are also specific watermark packages available but this might be one of the easiest ways to retain full control. Please note that I do not have `pic.png` so I replaced it by a generic picture. You may also want to use `geometry` instead of `fullpage`.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{fullpage, lipsum, tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[opacity=.1, inner sep=0pt]
    at(current page.center){\includegraphics[width=14cm,
    angle=45]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I was looking for... thanks a lot!