# Mirroring tikz page using current page coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to layout two pages such that the second is a mirror image of the first.

Looking at the previous answers on the subject here, I think I should be able to simply `xscale=-1` the second page, having put the tikz commands in a `\newcommand`, but it seems not to be working for me.  Is this maybe because I'm using `current page` coordinates?

How might I fix this, please?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,tikz]{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math} 

\begin{document}
    
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \newcommand{\wholepage}{
        \draw (current page.north east) -- (current page.south west);
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \wholepage
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \newpage

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, xscale=-1]
        \wholepage
    \end{tikzpicture}
        

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right in your supposition: the `current page` coordinates aren't affected by the `xscale`.  Could you add a little more detail about what you are trying to achieve?  It feels like you've simplified it a little bit too far for the question.

Comment: @AndrewStacey  The pages are to be printed duplex.  The back side of the page needs to be a mirror image of the front.  The front is built by a bunch of tikz commands and I'd rather not have to recode them all for the mirrored coordinate system, should there exist an alternative.

Comment: There are other options than redoing the tikz commands. `pgfmorepages` could handle this by putting a mirrored copy of the page, or if it is a single tikzpicture environment then save it in a box and mirror the entire box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `pgfmorepages` solution.  It defines a new layout, `1 on 2, 2nd mirrored` which repeats each page on a second page but mirrored.  This will work with anything on the page, whether it uses TikZ or not.  Underneath, each page is saved into a box which can then be manipulated before it is actually put on a page.  `pgf(more)pages` allows one to define layouts that do those various manipulations.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/639519/86}
\usepackage{pgfmorepages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{1 on 2, 2nd mirrored}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperheight}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperwidth}
  \def\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
  \def\pgfpageoptionbordercode{}
  \def\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout{1}
}
{
\pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
    physical pages=2,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth,%
    current logical shipout=\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout%
  }
  \pgfpagessetdefaults{%
    border code=\pgfpageoptionbordercode
  }
  \pgfpagesphysicalpage{1}{}
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
  \pgfpagesphysicalpage{2}{}
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      xscale=-1,%
      % If the above produces a spurious `1` in the middle of the page, use the two lines below instead
%      rotation=180,%
%      yscale=-1,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{1 on 2, 2nd mirrored}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\newpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The `lipsum` package is included just to generate some text.  When I tried it on one system (MikTeX) then the `xscale` version produced a spurious `1` somewhere on the page.  This didn't happen with my `TeXLive` distribution, so I'm guessing that my TikZ/PGF installation on the MikTeX system wasn't up to date.  Anyway, if you find a spurious `1` in the middle of the page when using `xscale` then remove that line and uncomment the lines `yscale` and `rotation`.  Or update your TikZ installation.

[image: each page is repeated and mirrored]

Comment: Many thanks Andrew, I tested this last night and it works great.  I'll have to check out the documentation for pgfmorepages though to understand it!  My printer's duplexer appears to be a tad petulant and doesn't /quite/ align the pages for the second pass identically which, in the spirit of William Morris, I would like to fix.  Is there a simple way to add an x,y translate for page 2?

Comment: @Ian I haven't tested it, but I'm almost certain that you can add an offset in the parameters of the `center` key on the second page.  If, say, it needs to be 4mm to the right then it would be `.5\pgfphysicalwidth+4mm`.

Answer (score 2):

I propose to have two separates commands for the two pages (avoid one command with `xscale=-1`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\wholedown}{%
        \draw[cyan!30,line width=3pt](current page.north west) -- (current page.south east);
    }
    \newcommand{\wholeup}{%
        \draw[cyan!30,line width=3pt](current page.south west)--(current page.north east);
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \wholeup
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newpage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \wholedown
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you consider to repeat all this for all the document, you can think to use the `background` package for odd and even pages.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on these two:

- [Background image on every page with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527456/background-image-on-every-page-with-tikz)
- [Using modulo operation to draw graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168896/using-modulo-operation-to-draw-graph)

This MWE uses the package `eso-pic` to create a background image through `tikz` and `xscale`. The syntax `xscale={2*Mod(\thepage,2)-1}` result in `-1` and `+1` for even and odd pages. `Mod` is the modulo operation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation.

Package `background` still is another option to be considered.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{fullpage, lipsum, tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[opacity=.5, inner sep=0pt, xscale={2*Mod(\thepage,2)-1}] 
      at(current page.center)
      {\includegraphics[width=14cm, angle=45]{example-image-duck}}; %*(\thepage-1)
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using `background` and `tikz`.

The following MWE presents the crossed lines on even and odd pages. The `\includegraphics` is just an extra as illustration of what is flipped and what is not. The first `tikzpicture` draws the borders, which may be removed. The second `tikzpicture` uses `\pgfmathparse` from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6709/using-pgfmathparse-and-ifnum-for-a-tikz-checkerboard) to change behavior acoordingly to even and odd pages. Both `\path[fill=<color>]` are proofs of concept derived from the linked answer. The command `\draw` draws the crossed blue lines. I used `(+/-<measure>,+/-<measure>)` as a lazy shortcut to display the lines at the same coordinate of the borders. Those points may be replaced for other commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  color=black,
  opacity=0.4,
  angle=0,
  position = current page.south west,
  nodeanchor = south west,
  hshift = 1.5cm, % horizontal margin
  vshift = 1.5cm, % vertical margin
  contents={%
    \includegraphics[
    height=\dimexpr\paperheight-3cm\relax, % double the vert. margin
    width=\dimexpr\paperwidth-3cm\relax    % double the horiz. margin
    ]{example-image-duck}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \draw [opacity=1,line width=2pt]
      ($ (current page.north west) + (1.5cm,-1.5cm) $)
      rectangle
      ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.5cm,1.5cm) $);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture, blue]
      \pgfmathparse{int(Mod(\thepage,2))}
      \let\r\pgfmathresult
      \ifnum\r=1
        \path[fill=red] (current page.north west) circle (1cm);
        \draw [opacity=1,line width=2pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (1.5cm,-1.5cm) $)
        --
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.5cm,1.5cm) $);
      \else
        \path[fill=blue] (current page.south east) circle (1cm);
        \draw [opacity=1,line width=2pt]
        ($ (current page.north east) + (-1.5cm,-1.5cm) $)
        --
        ($ (current page.south west) + (1.5cm,1.5cm) $);
      \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\BgThispage
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]